# navbar with 0 space before

Tags: html, css

I just started doing a `navbar` and there is a space before first item and I can't get delete it. I tried with `margin` 0 and `padding` 0 on `.navbar a`, didn't work

I'm sure I'm missing something :D

```css
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  padding: 17px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: honeydew;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class='navbar'>
      <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#download'>Download</a></li>
      <li><a href='#register'>Register</a></li>
      <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href='#FAQ'>FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: can you screenshot a problem

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BBPyfQe that space marked with red :D

Comment: you can try to add `padding: 0;` to body and `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to `.navbar li` and maybe `.navbar ul`
Edit: Try to add `padding-left: 0` to `.navbar a:first-of-type` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `padding: 0;` to .navbar in your style.

The space is created by the `ul` element, not the `li`elements.

```
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0; /* <--- here */
}
```

Comment: lol was that easy, thanks!

Comment: @GabrielDaniel Please don't forget to `validate` an answer and `upvote` **all** usefull answer ;)

Comment: i don't forget, it's just a deelay

Answer (score 2):

It's tag `ul` has padding, in your case add `padding: 0;` to your `.navbar`

```css
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  padding: 17px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: honeydew;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class='navbar'>
      <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#download'>Download</a></li>
      <li><a href='#register'>Register</a></li>
      <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href='#FAQ'>FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ul` element in html have naturally a `padding-left` css rule set to `40px`. Since your `.navbar` is actually a `ul` element you will have to remove it:

```css
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 0;    /* <-- Reset padding-left from ul */
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 17px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: honeydew;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class='navbar'>
            <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#download'>Download</a></li>
            <li><a href='#register'>Register</a></li>
            <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href='#FAQ'>FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```